# Why edits are not showing

Tags: support

I flagged an answer as "Not an answer". I saw later that OP changed the answer and now it is completely meaningful and appropriate. But I am wondering the edit is not showing. How is it possible?

Comment: Links? Without links we would never know...

Comment: An edit that is less than 5 min (? not sure about the minutes) from the first post will not show as a new revision. This is so that the user can fix typos and similar.

Comment: The first answer by [jdthood](http://askubuntu.com/questions/404117/cannot-access-internet-due-to-tampering-with-resolv-conf)

Comment: I think it should show a "an edit has been made; click to load" bar if an edit was submitted, even in the 5 min grace period. The grace period is briefly explained at the bottom of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/232872) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit a post within 5 minutes of the latest version (that you submitted) then it will count as one edit. This is so that users can fix typos and formatting issues without having too many revisions.

Why is it bad with many revisions? Well after 10 revisions on a question it will automatically become a community wiki. On a community wiki you do not earn any reputation from it. So from not having too many questions becoming a community wiki automatically there's a 5 minute fix time.

Hope that is what you asked for.

Comment: probably this would be the case and for any reason my browser did not refreshed in the mean time. And I missed the update. Thanks